# Подлежащее «кто» и сказуемое женском роде

Tags: согласование, род

Увидела такое предложение: «Вы узнаете, кто из фавориток так и не смог ответить Павлу I взаимностью»

Разве не должно сказуемое «смог» стоять в женском роде, ведь речь идёт о фаворитКАХ?

Comment: Местоимение **кто** не имеет **рода** и **числа**.
https://russky.info/ru/grammar/pronouns

Answer (score 2):

Нет, здесь идет речь не о фавортиках, а о том, КТО НЕ СМОГ.
Вы можете с легкостью опустить словосочетание «из фавориток», и предложение не потеряет свой смысл (если из контекста понятно, что обсуждается тема фавориток): **«Вы узнаете, кто так и не смог ответить Павлу I взаимностью»**.

Если по каким-либо причинам вам необходимо согласовать глагол «смог» именно с женским родом, можно изменить предложение следующим образом: **«Вы узнаете, какая фаворитка так и не смогла ответить Павлу I взаимностью»**. Но здесь мы опять же будем согласовывать глагол «смогла» не с одиночным словом «фаворитка», а со словосочетанием «какая фаворитка».

Answer (score 1):

***Вы узнаете, кто из фавориток так и не смог ответить Павлу I взаимностью.***

[Согласование сказуемого и подлежащего](http://www.mylanguage.ru/materials/127/3139)

При местоимении **кто** сказуемые – глаголы ставятся в **единственном** числе, а в прошедшем времени - в **мужском** роде, независимо от числа деятелей и от их принадлежности к мужскому или женскому полу: ***Кто присутствовал на последнем заседании?***

Сказуемое при местоимениях ***некто, кто-то, никто*** и других сказуемое ставится в **единственном числе** **(в прошедшем времени – в форме мужского рода**, *даже если речь идёт о лице женского пола*), например:

***Некто написал следующее…; Кто-то из конькобежек выступил плохо.***

Примечание. **Постановка сказуемого в женском роде** после такого подлежащего **возможна в том случае**, если есть **уточняющий или пояснительный оборот с ведущим словом – существительным в форме женского рода**:

*Никто из девушек, даже Зоя, не нашлась, что сказать.*